# Is possible to listen on Redux @@INIT action in middleware

Tags: redux, redux-saga, redux-middleware

In Redux, there is initial action `@@INIT`.

Is possible to dispatch another action (in middleware) when this action occurred?

If not, what is best alternative to push action after store is ready?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

According to https://github.com/reactjs/redux/issues/186

`@@INIT`

- internal action
- name of that action may differ in dev mode, so if you use it - it might broke app functionality or automatic reloading
- to sum-up, this action should not be touched in app codebase

**How to push initial `Redux` actions then?**

Without library:

```
const store = createStore(...);
store.dispatch(...)
```

In middleware like `Redux Saga`:

```
function * initialSaga() {
   yield put({ ... })
}
export default function * root() {
   yield fork(initialSaga);
}
```